# Showing specific values in an STFT plot

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, python, stft, scipy

I have a short term fourier transform plot that I plot using matplotlib's `pcolormesh()` function:
[image: stft]

If I zoom in the plot, I see this:
[image: stft_zoomed]

Now, I want the plot to just show the zoomed-in range on the y-axis - till 4 or 3 kHz. Is there any way to do this without having to manually zoom in? I want to do a comparison for multiple waveforms in the frequency range as this is my passband in the passband filter I apply on the data.

Here is the code I use to compute and plot the stft:

```
sampleFreq, segmentTimes, stftX = sp.stft(filteredY, fs)
segmentTimes += (1.5 / 1000)
plt.pcolormesh(segmentTimes, sampleFreq, np.abs(stftX), shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.title("Sort Term FFT")
plt.show()
```

I add 1.5 to the `segmentTimes` because I trim my original data from 1.5 to 2.5 ms, and for some reason, if I don't add 1.5 here, the stft starts from 0.0 s. And the division by 1000 is for conversion to seconds from milliseconds.

Also, `sampleFreq` and `segmentTimes` are simple lists but `stftX` is a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use matplotlib.pyplot's `axis()` [function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) as follows:

```
# show section based on bandpass filter cut-off frequencies
plt.title("Zoomed Short Term Fourier Transform")
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Frequency Magnitude")
plt.pcolormesh(self.segment_times, self.sample_freq, self.abs_stft, shading='gouraud')
plt.axis([self.segment_times[0], self.segment_times[-1], high_pass, low_pass])

plt.show()
```

where `high_pass` and `low_pass` are the frequency cut-offs within which you want to display the y-axis data.